# Do I need to get the interest of all people here before I ask a question?

Tags: discussion, comments

I posted a question yesterday: [Why does the Department of Mysteries keep prophecies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152617/why-does-the-department-of-mysteries-keep-prophecies?noredirect=1#comment395348_152617)

And somebody dropped a comment saying

> "I can't understand why people ask topics here that are not even
>   significant"

and then I replied with

> "if so, can you give me the details what's significant for you and
>   what's significant for others? I assumed this site is for asking
>   questions passing the guidelines and are on-topic and not what
>   interest all users in here. That's a pretty hard thing for me to do."

I won't be able to post the actual comment because the user had deleted their comment.

It disappointed me that somebody would say **"hey what kind of post is that? It isn't interesting at all!"**

What I thought is that I just need to follow the guidelines in posting a question here. On-topic, duplicate avoidance, not opinion-based, and so on and so forth. But is getting the interest of **all the users here** also in the guidelines? Are **significant questions for some** allowed and **significant questions for me and for some others** not allowed? That's what disappointed me.

Maybe some will tell me this is just a small matter but I want to know if it is necessary to post a question that's important for all of the users here. Maybe some of you will give me advice. Do I need to get the interest of all people here before I ask a question?

Comment: The reason for the comment is _likely_ (the comment wasn't mine, so this is guesswork, which is why I'm not posting it as an answer) to have something to do the large number of very speculative "what-if" [tag:harry-potter] questions this stack has. Yours isn't too bad, but we've seen questions along the lines of "what if two wizards simultaneously disarm another wizard while one apparates and the other disapparates, while their victim is looking at a basilisk via the Mirror of Erised which is the eighth horcrux made by a time-turner wielding squib". (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) In other words, questions focusing on minor details of the _Harry Potter_ universe, which were never quite thought through by the author. This has tired some people of questions that can only (at this point, at least — there's still content added to _Pottermore_ and by the new _Fantastic Beasts_ films) be answered by speculation. I myself don't hold this opinion, I simply ignore questions if I should find them uninteresting, although in [chat] I occasionally make fun of the worst ones. It's not limited to [tag:harry-potter], by the way; we've had a string of questions on Toad's spit.

Comment: @SQB I understand what you are trying to say. That's why I don't ask *what if* questions, because I thought it wouldn't be included in the story. But at some point, I'd seen questions using this style and find them interesting. But I asked this because I want to know the reason behind those orbs, I thought they were just existing for nothing. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Don't worry about it.

There's no question which will interest *everyone*. For that matter, there's no single sci-fi or fantasy franchise (not Harry Potter, not Star Wars, not Lord of the Rings) which will interest *everyone*. For any given question on this site, there will always be people who find it uninteresting. So **no, you don't have to interest every single user with each question you ask**. It simply wouldn't be feasible.

If someone leaves a comment which says essentially "I don't find this question interesting" without explaining why or offering any constructive criticism, feel free to flag it as "not constructive". And please, **don't let it get to you!**

> But does getting interest of all the users here is also in the guidelines? Does the significant questions for some are allowed and the significant questions for me and for some are not allowed?

Please don't take a grumpy comment from a single user as a reflection of site policy. From the voting it's quite clear that the majority of people who saw your question liked and appreciated it. There'll always be at least one person who doesn't like a given question; that *doesn't at all mean* it's somehow not acceptable for the site. Keep your chin up, and keep on posting nice questions :-)

Answer (score 11):

TL;DR: No, you don't need to get the interest of all people. People who leave such comments are wrong, you're right.

1. I don't understand why people bother not only reading, but leaving rude comments on questions they don't find interesting.

   **Live and let live**. For every question your opinionated self finds un-interesting/boring/meh, there are people who both find that question interesting; AND likely find some of the questions you personally like boring/uninteresting/meh.

   If we rid the site of the types of questions any small group of people dislikes... likelyhood is, we would be left with a site that has about 100 total questions.

   If you feel strongly enough to leave such a comment, and think enough people agree with you, post a proposal on Meta to bar specific question types. If you know that most people will disagree, stop posting hurtful comments to people whose only crime is not sharing your personal minority opinion of what's interesting.
2. If you as a user and especially question asker see such a comment:

   Ignore it, say non-nice things *in your head* about opinionated self-important person who left it, or better yet flag it (if moderators agree, as rude and offensive; otherwise, as not constructive).

   As long as your question doesn't have 2:1 or worse downvote/upvote ratio, such comments are meaningless, mean attacks that don't reflect anything but someone's personal opinion, and most certainly don't reflect your doing something wrong you should feel bad about as a question asker..
3. More personally, negative attitudes like the ones exhibited by the comment being asked about (as well as general unwillingness to abide by "live and live" approach) were one of the top reasons that drove me away from SFF as a user.

Comment: I thought you left because your apprentice went craaaaazy and killed all of your pupils?

Comment: @Valorum - given Jedi instructions, i would consider *staying* to be the crazy choice

Comment: @Valorum - also, given rep charts, I'm'agona claim YOU were my apprentice :))))

Comment: What is thy bidding, my master?

Comment: @Valorum - isn't the more context appropriate quote "Now, ***I*** am the master!" ? :)